# tubular bells in well known classical and modern music pieces

Tags: classical-music, instrumental

I'm part of music group that consists of three violinists, trumpet player (who can also play piano) and piano player/percussionist. For an upcoming event we have to include some songs with tubular bells in our repertoire. I looked up songs that feature tubular bells (for example in link below), but I didn't really like any of them.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_bells#Other_uses

So my question is which songs would, in your opinion, sound good if we replace one instrument with tubular bells or add them.

I would prefer classical or film pieces, but genre is actually not the most important in this case. Songs have to be well known or at least really attractive to listen to, because audience will consist of "normal" (not musicians) people. :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, somewhat opinion-based, but the [Harry Potter theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x8DvkC1KH4). Here it is for example,played on a carillion, but you get an idea of how it might sound with bells plus other instruments. Likewise the [Game of Thrones theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuyavOdOHUE).

Comment: Like @ChrisSunami says, pls post video of your music for the event. Unexpected arrangements of any tune are always great...

Comment: I will certainly try to remember that (event is in June). ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is strictly opinion, but what about Pachelbel's *Canon in D*, with the bells doing the baseline?  It's often done with an organ, and the bells have a somewhat similar timbre.  I also feel like *Pictures at an Exhibition* could sound good with bells.

Maybe Grieg's *Hall of the Mountain King*?  The bells could add a bit of mystery.

Comment: I love Pictures at an Exhibition and Hall of the Mountain King ideas! We will try Canon in D as well. Thank you! It's a shame that multiple answers cannot be "accepted". :)

Comment: True, but you can vote up as many answers as you like :)  When you do it, I'd love it if you would come back and post a recording.

Comment: Good idea. I will try not to forget (event is in June). :)